# error in loading a file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, video-processing

I want to load a video in yuv extension using the function load.

```
load foreman_qcif.yuv
```

But I get this error

```
??? Error using ==> load
Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file C:\Users\Chaine\Downloads\foreman_qcif.yuv
"Øÿ".
```

Also, I would like to place the values or parameters of that video into a cell array. I found a function "struct2cell" but I think I used incorrectly. How must I manipulate the digital video in frames using matrices for each frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load` is for loading `.mat` files (MATLAB data files) or ASCII files, see [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/load.html) for more details.

You probably want to use the [`VideoReader`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html) class, but you'll need to convert your file into a supported file format first.

Comment: @wangdongchaine How can you use what? The `VideoReader` class? Read the doc! It's got various methods, including one called `read`. There are some examples in the doc. As I said you first need to convert your file to a supported file format.

Answer (score 1):

I think there don't exist way to read (or, load) **YUV** files. Function **load** exists only for MAT files (.mat).

Check these links:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6318

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36417-yuv-files-reading-and-converting